# How to pass dropDown list Selected data to another table and update that table in asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

The control class saves the input data into Invoice table.

This is my control class

```
public ActionResult UpdateInvoice()
{   var getProduct = db.InventoryTbs.ToList();
        SelectList list = new SelectList(getProduct, "PId", "PName", "PPrice");
        ViewBag.Product = list;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateInvoice(InvoiceTb idetail)
{
    if (Session["User"] == null)    // doesn't work
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {

            db.InvoiceTbs.Add(idetail);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("ShowInvoice");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `UpdateInvoice.cshtml`. Here if I input the Lquantity and Bill value gets saved into the `Invoice` table.

I have created dropdown list that shows item present in another table(inventory). But it doesnot add to Invoice table.
After entering the quantity I want it to calculate the bill taking selected product price from inventory table

I have tried Json and some other ways but finding no luck.

```
@model TallyBook_Store_Management_System.Models.InvoiceTb

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UpdateInvoice";
    var product = ViewBag.Product;
}

<h2>UpdateInvoice</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>InvoiceTb</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ListName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList( "Product", "Select")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ListName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LQuantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LQuantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LQuantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Bill, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Bill, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Bill, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by passing drop down list selected data from view to controller. Then I have updated the specific database table in Controller.

If there is another efficient or good ways Please do share, I would like to  learn more better approaches.